# Retrieving all people from the Wikipedia API

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

I'm wanting to find all people in the Wikipedia database using their API. So far, my approach to this task has been to use a query to fetch all people who belong to a category, such as:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=100&cmtitle=Category:French_revolutionaries

This approach requires me to know that French_revolutionaries is a category of people. My question is: How can one retrieve all people (not just the people in a category) from the API?

One approach I considered was to start with an arbitrary category, such as French_revolutionaries. For each member of that category, retrieve their information and the other categories to which they belong, and then search for those categories in the same fashion, operating in this recursive fashion until there were no new categories to fetch. This wouldn't work if the network isn't fully connected, though, and is less elegant than I'd like.

Is there a straightforward way to find all people in the wikipedia database? Can dbpedia provide that array? I'm downloading a [SQL dump of the Wiki category data](ftp://wikipedia.c3sl.ufpr.br/wikipedia/enwiki/20160701/) right now, but wanted to raise the question in case others know of a fast solution. Any help others can offer will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is tagged with Sparql, so I assume you're open to Sparql- based solutions.  Is there a problem with a query like

```
select * { ?person a dbo:Person }
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+*+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fperson+a+dbo%3APerson%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Nice, I was just looking around and saw lots of your earlier Sparql queries as well. I came up with SELECT ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf
    WHERE {
      { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology> ?property ?hasValue }
      UNION
      { ?isValueOf ?property <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> }
    }  but this is much less compact than your solution!

Comment: @duhaime sure, it just turns into `?person a dbo:Person ; dbo:wikiPageID ?id`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I realized that the responses contain wikipedia 'titles' which can serve the same purpose as the id at least as far as the API is concerned. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps with Wikidata

```
SELECT ?person WHERE { ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 }
limit 100
```

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fperson%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20%7D%0Alimit%20100